# zlib error on gem install rails after rvm version switch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

(Debian squeeze)
rvm version: 1.10.0

I have just installed ruby 1.9.2-p290 using "rvm install 1.9.2" and made it default. However, I am getting this error when trying to install rails using rubygems. "gem install rails" worked fine on my system ruby installation.

> root:/usr/bin# rvm list
>
> rvm rubies
>
> => ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i686 ]
>
> root:/usr/bin# rvm current ruby-1.9.2-p290 root:/usr/bin# gem list
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> root:/usr/bin# gem install rails ERROR:  Loading command: install
>   (LoadError)
>       no such file to load -- zlib
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
>       uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

I have tried the instructions on this other page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441248/rvm-ruby-1-9-1-troubles, (apt-get install zlib, reinstalling 1.9.2 on rvm), but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas of what might be the root problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **the dev package** for zlib before installing ruby with rvm. Assuming you are using Debian or Ubuntu,

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2
```

should do it.